# How to generate a list starting from a string and ending with another?

Tags: python-3.x, list, file

I am trying to read a list of wavelengths from a text file containing a lot of other information but I can't figure out how to make python only start adding to the list after 'wavelength'.  I can get it to end at } however.  I'm sure I'm missing something painfully obvious. My text file has wavelengths stored in this format:

```
info1 = {xxx}
info2 = {xxx}

Wavelength = {
1.1,
2.2,
3.3
}

info3 = {
1.1,
2.2
}
```

I was able to get it to read into a list by finding what lines the data was in and reading in that range, but I want this to be more adaptable.

```
wavelength = []
with open(header, 'r') as hdr:
    for line in hdr:
        if 'wavlength' in line:
            #add next lines to list until }
            if float in line:
                if '}' in line:
                    break
    wavelength.append(line)
print(wavelength)

#output I want
[1.1,2.2,3.3]
#output I get
['}\n']
```

I know how to remove special characters and new lines so I'm not worried about that so much as reading the next lines until I hit }.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the file, and get all lines, then find the indexes of 
`Wavelength = {` and the next `}`, then select the floats between them. 
Getting all lines also helps you if you want to process more data using the lines later

```
wavelength = []

with open('file.txt', 'r') as hdr:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in hdr.readlines() if line.strip()]

#Find the index of Wavelength = {
start_idx = lines.index('Wavelength = {')

#Find the index of next }
end_idx = lines.index('}',start_idx)

#Get all floats between those indexes
wavelength = [float(item.strip(',')) for item in lines[start_idx+1:end_idx]]
print(wavelength)
```

The output will be

```
[1.1, 2.2, 3.3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to keep track of whether you've found 'wavelength' or not.
You could store it in a variable named `found_wave_length` which is initially `False`, but as soon as you find it, set to `True`. You only append lines if `found_wave_length` is true.

```py
wavelength = []
found_wave_length = False
with open('file.txt', 'r') as hdr:
    for line in hdr:
        if 'Wavelength' in line:
            found_wave_length = True
            continue

        if found_wave_length and '}' in line:
            break

        if found_wave_length:
            #add next lines to list until }
            wavelength.append(line)
print(wavelength)
```

Comment: Trying this I just got an empty list.  It could be because I have data above and below my wavelength data.  I updated what my text file looks like.

Comment: Because the spelling is important. In your file `Wavelength` starts with a capital `W` but not in the code...

Comment: Sorry!  That's usually my downfall, but even with that correction I still get an empty list for some reason.  I'm fairly new to this so I'm sure it's something trivial.

Comment: Edited the code, forget my other comments. I was exiting when I found a `}` - even if that happened before finding the `Wavelength`. Now I'm asserting that `found_wave_length` is true before `break`ing out of the loop.

Comment: It still returns an empty list, @Devesh Kumar Singh 's solution worked.  I'm still curious what I did wrong with your code haha.  Thank you!

Comment: You could try adding a `print(line)` after `for line in hdr:` to see which lines it's actually parsing.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to simply check if the current line is a number.

```
for line in hdr.splitlines():
    try:
        num = float(line)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        wavelength.append(num)
```

The brackets and file format aren't taken into account, but this could be implemented by setting a boolean flag.

```
switch = False
...
with open('file.txt', 'r') as hdr:
    for line in hdr.splitlines():
        if switch:
            wavelength.append(num)

        if 'Wavelength' in line and '{' in line:
            switch = True
        elif '}' in line:
            switch = False
```

And you could use regex to tidy it up if you like (e.g. `re.search('Wavelength *{', line)`).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without any loops. All string methods can be chained together for compactness.

```
with open(header, 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
temp = s.partition('Wavelength = {')[2] # Get everything after 'Wavelength = {'
temp = temp.partition('}')[0]           # Get everything before the following '}'
temp = temp.split(',\n')                # Separate individual numbers
wavelength = [float(k) for k in temp]   # Convert to float
```

Comment: Nice. But isn't the array constructor a loop? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple short version of it. Start after 'Wavelength' , end at '}', lots of other info in the file, just like you said.

```
    wavelength = []
    flag = 0
    for line in open('wavefile.txt','r'):
        if '}' in line:
            flag = 0
        if 'Wavelength' in line:
            flag = 1
            continue
        if flag == 1:
            wavelength.append(line.strip())

    print(wavelength)
```